# Java Spring REST Api with images (files)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest

I am creating a REST API using Java Spring with MongoDB. I have a Model with some attributes like name and price and I want the user to be able to upload an image with each of these objects into the database. So i need a way to make the API take files (images) and store them on the server and save the link to access the file in the database so that with a get request the user is able to get the link to access the image.

Could anyone give me some hint or ressource on how to build this using Java Spring and MongoDB?
I would be very thankful if you could give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's the best practice. But let me try.

```java
// Use "multipart/form-data"
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity example(
@RequestPart(value = "jsonData") String json, // a string in the form of json "{\"id\": 12}"
@RequestPart(value = "image") MultipartFile image // an image file
) {
  try {
     // convert the json string into an object you define.
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    [YOUR_JSON_OBJECT] hello = mapper.readValue(jsonString, [YOUR_JSON_OBJECT_HERE].class);
    // upload the file
    ...
    // save the object into the database
    ...
     return ResponseEntity.ok();
  } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
     // if the string is a wrong form of json,
     return ResponseEntity.badRequest();
  }
}
```

Hope you have a hint.

Happy Coding!